# Get date info from a folder in Linux and save in a column in my DF

Tags: python, pandas, linux

Not sure exactly how to ask that question, but here it goes.

I have this df :

df

```
JOB_STREAM_NAME         JOB_NAME                        JOB_Command
0   P26_NEXT_MAU_TOD    PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D     /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D.sh
1   P26_NEXT_MAU_TOD    PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D     /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D.sh
2   P26_NEXT_NBA_TOD    PP_NEXT_NBA_AS110001_D          /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh
3   P26_AAIN_TOD        PP_AAIN_SPARK_CDLC_ING_DFLT_D   /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/iws/call_run_extract_default.sh cdlc_ing
```

and I want to get the date(from Linux SO) in the 4th item of the tree structure in the JOB_COMMAND

Folder `aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus`:

```
[m292121@mz-vl-vb-415 ~]$ ll /data/application/AANX/
total 1348
ldrwxrwsr-x 12 root bgdt 4096 Sep 26 11:30 aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus
```

Here, there is no 4th item, so it gets the last, which is a file call_nba_as11.sh

```
[m292121@al-vl-vb-408 ~]$ ll /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh
-rwxrwsr-x 1 root bgdt 371 Sep 20 19:20 /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh
```

Folder `aain-srv-motor-extracao-next`:

```
[m292121@mz-vl-vb-415 ~]$ ll /data/application/AAIN/
total 136
ldrwxrwsr-x 12 root bgdt 4096 Jul 15 10:30 aain-srv-motor-extracao-next
```

Basically I trying to achieve this

df

```
JOB_STREAM_NAME         JOB_NAME                        Last_Update         JOB_Command
0   P26_NEXT_MAU_TOD    PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D     2022-09-26 11:30:00 /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D.sh
1   P26_NEXT_MAU_TOD    PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D     2022-09-26 11:30:00 /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D.sh
2   P26_NEXT_NBA_TOD    PP_NEXT_NBA_AS110001_D          2022-09-20 19:20:00 /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh
3   P26_AAIN_TOD        PP_AAIN_SPARK_CDLC_ING_DFLT_D   2022-07-15 10:30:00 /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/iws/call_run_extract_default.sh cdlc_ing
```

I thought to split the JOB_COMMAND into a new column and use it to do the search, but I still need to figure out how to get the info.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "JOB_STREAM_NAME": [
            "P26_NEXT_MAU_TOD",
            "P26_NEXT_MAU_TOD",
            "P26_NEXT_NBA_TOD",
            "P26_AAIN_TOD",
        ],
        "JOB_NAME": [
            "PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D",
            "PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D",
            "PP_NEXT_NBA_AS110001_D",
            "PP_AAIN_SPARK_CDLC_ING_DFLT_D",
        ],
        "JOB_Command": [
            "/data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D.sh",
            "/data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D.sh",
            "/data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh",
            "/data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/iws/call_run_extract_default.sh cdlc_ing",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it using Python standard library [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) and [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) modules:

```py
import datetime
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path


def get_fourth_elem(file_path):
    """Helper function.

    Args:
        file_path: file path as a string.

    Returns:
        absolute path to the fourth element (or last one if shorter) as a Pathlib object.
    """
    file_path_length = len(file_path.strip("/").split("/"))
    file_path = Path(file_path)
    if file_path_length > 4:
        for _ in range(file_path_length - 4):
            file_path = Path(file_path.parent)
        return file_path
    else:
        return file_path
```

```py
df["Last_Update"] = df["JOB_Command"].apply(
    lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        get_fourth_elem(x).stat().st_mtime
    ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%H:%S")
    if Path(x).exists()
    else np.nan
)
df = df.reindex(columns=["JOB_STREAM_NAME", "JOB_NAME", "Last_Update", "JOB_Command"])
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
JOB_STREAM_NAME         JOB_NAME                        Last_Update         JOB_Command
0   P26_NEXT_MAU_TOD    PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D     2022-09-26 11:30:00 /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D.sh
1   P26_NEXT_MAU_TOD    PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D     2022-09-26 11:30:00 /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D.sh
2   P26_NEXT_NBA_TOD    PP_NEXT_NBA_AS110001_D          2022-09-20 19:20:00 /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh
3   P26_AAIN_TOD        PP_AAIN_SPARK_CDLC_ING_DFLT_D   2022-07-15 10:30:00 /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/iws/call_run_extract_default.sh cdlc_ing
```

Comment: hey man, thanks I was off for a couple of days, will try your suggestion later on, thanks

Comment: Hey @Laurent, just tried you suggestion, apparently is not working

have a look in the scenario:

the JOB_Command : /data/application/ADAT/adat-srv-ingestao-dados/src/SIBA/call-iws/01-spark/PP_ADAT_SPRK_EXP_0001_S.sh

the output : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'adat-srv-ingestao-dados'

And I have the folder : [m292121@mz-vl-vb-415 ~]$ ls /data/application/ADAT/adat-srv-ingestao-dados/
adat_srv_ingestao_dados.egg-info  config.cfg  env  env.tar.gz  fortify-debug  fortify-output  fortify-scripts  README.md  requirements.txt  setup.py  src

Comment: Right. I've updated my answer with a more robust approach. Cheers.

Comment: it worked for the sample I mentioned previously, but now, when I'm using all the data from my df, got this error:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not float

Comment: I guess you have some data cleaning to do, as this message suggests that at least one value in `JOB_Command` is not of type string, but float. I understand my answer solved your question as you posted it, so please consider accepting it. Cheers.